# How to Install PHP bcmath extension on server without Shell?

Tags: php, server, admin, sudo, yum

I know there are several questions related to this, but I dont have access to shell, how can I install without shell script?

I know I can install this via sudo and yumm

```
yum install php-bcmath

sudo install php-bcmath
```

Any help?

Comment: Is this on a shared hoster? Your hosting provider might offer the option to manage the installed PHP-extensions via some Dashboard or something similar.